# Is this way to create object really better? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I have reading this book and of course by using constructor would be better while creating more objects and was told less typing too but then to the end of the chapter it is giving another option for creating an object which actually requires lots of typing and makes me feel like just making an object literal in a different way.

Let's say a car object for example:

```
function Car(make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.convertible = convertible;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.started = false;
    this.start = function(){
        this.started = true;
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        this.started = false;
    };
    this.drive = function(){
        if(this.started){
            console.log(this.make + " " + this.model + " goes zoom zoom!");
        }else{
            console.log("Start the engine first.");
        }
    }
}
```

Creating new Car objects

```
var chevy = new Car("Chevy", "Bel Air", 1957, "red", 2, false, 1021);
var cadi = new Car("GM", "Cadillac", 1955, "tan", 5, false, 12892);
var taxi = new Car("Webville Motors", "Taxi", 1955, "yellow", 4, false, 281341);
var fiat = new Car("Fiat", "500", 1957, "Medium Blue", 2, false, 88000);
var testCar = new Car("Webville Motors", "Test Car", 2014, "marine", 2, true, 21)
```

I can understand all the above but what the book suggested a better and another way which requires more typing is store those params into another variable and change the constructor like this

```
function Car(params){
    this.make = params.make;
    this.model = params.model;
    this.year = params.year;
    this.color = params.color;
    this.passengers = params.passengers;
    this.convertible = params.convertible;
    this.mileage = params.mileage;
    this.started = false;
    this.start = function(){
        this.started = true;
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        this.started = false;
    };
    this.drive = function(){
        if(this.started){
            console.log(this.make + " " + this.model + " goes zoom zoom!");
        }else{
            console.log("Start the engine first.");
        }
    }
}

var chevyParam = {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Bel Air",
    year: 1957,
    color: "red",
    passengers: 2,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 1021
}

var chevy = new Car(chevyParam);
```

Like I understand what is happening and how this works but is the second one really a lot better and neater than the first one? I know the second one doesn't have to care if entering the params in the wrong order but a lot more works

Comment: simpler to change an object than modify parameters and arguments and make sure they are all in the correct order

Comment: "Better is in the eye of the developer" (c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are good.  'Good' means "having the qualities required for a particular role." according to google.  If it meets your needs it is good.

However some methods of doing things are generally dissaproved of by most of the programming community as being unexplicit(unreadable) or hacky. These two methods you described are neither hacky nor unexplicit, they just cater to different needs.

**Method 1:**

- Less readable
- It would potentially be easier to mix up variables, and isn't obvious to someone reviewing your code.
- It's much shorter

Personally I think for simple objects with few attributes, the first method is most appropriate.

**Method 2:**

- Quite readable
- Arguably harder to mix up variables, and a bit more obvious to someone reviewing your code.
- It's a bit longer

With more complex objects, such as a car, you might want to use the second method as it is more explicit and values can be out of order without breaking anything.

Also consider adding defaults by doing so: `this.model = params.model || ”default model if params.model is undefined”;`

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are perfectly valid.  What I would argue is that it is more important to be consistent across what you're doing.  If you are making objects using both methodologies (parameter objects and a bunch of variables passed in the header) then THAT is sloppy code.  It's sort of like ' vs " in JS.  They both do essentially the same thing, what's most important is that you are consistent in your code with which you use.